# XIB file using default ViewController class instead of what is set in file's owner

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Before anyone flags this as a duplicate I have thoroughly searched Stack Overflow and none of the suggestions have helped.

The problem:  I have added a custom view to my `Master-Detail app` that is pushed on top of the master view when a `button` is clicked.  I have set the File's Owner of the `xib` file to be the custom class.  If I make even a single `IBOutlet` connection the app crashes and says "class is not key value coding-compliant for the key"  I have placed an `NSLog` into the `viewDidLoad` function of my custom class and I am seeing that it is never being instantiated.  I feel like I am probably missing a really simple step but from what I can tell from all of the other posts with this issue, their solutions do not work for me.

SettingsViewController.m:

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@interface SettingsViewController ()

@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Line of code that starts the view:

```
UIViewController *settingsViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES];
```

Things I have already tried via stack overflow:

1. make sure the File's Owner class is set to custom class name
2. make sure there are not any extra `IBOutlets` in the `viewcontroller` that have been deleted or renamed in the code
3. delete the files and recreate them
4. clean project, `kill xcode`, delete the app off the device, reopen `xcode` and rebuild project
5. rebuild the project from scratch

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
UIViewController *settingsViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
```

should be:

```
SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
```

The name of the file owner class is basically just information for IB to tell it what connections are available. It isn't actually used during the instantiation. By calling `[[UIViewController alloc] ...` you are creating a plain `UIViewController` instance (which obviously doesn't have your keys defined).

Comment: that worked perfectly, I knew it would be something simple like that. Thanks!!